# How would the Istanbul Canal allow Turkey to bypass the Montreux Convention?

Tags: international-law, turkey

According to multiple sources as cited by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Istanbul_Canal#Criticism) (such as [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20110430073318/http://www.todayszaman.com/news-223806-istanbul-canal-project-to-open-debate-on-montreux-convention.html), or [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20181211162128/https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/turkey-debates-whether-international-treaty-is-obstacle-to-plan-to-bypass-the-bosporus/2011/04/29/AFcaFrCF_story.html)), the now-under-construction Istanbul Canal would allow Turkey to bypass the *Montreux Convention Regarding the Regime of the Straits*.

I'm not sure how that is possible. The [preamble](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Montreux_Convention#Preamble) of the Convention clearly speaks of the

> Straits of the Dardanelles, the Sea. of Marmora and the Bosphorus comprised under the general term " Straits "

The same wording, the use of plural Straits, is use throughout the document. Thus, I imagine, the scope of the Convention is broader than just the Bosphorus. Even if there was a canal bypassing the Dardanelles (which I believe doesn't exist, even as a plan), the Convention would still apply when navigating though the Sea of Marmara. Which is exactly where the Bosphorus Canal would lead from the Black Sea.

I mean, sure, Turkey could transfer, or allow the transfer of, ships from the Black Sea to the Sea of Marmara freely, but that's it. I don't see how that would bypass the Convention in any substantial way.

---

Clarification: I think the point of the Convention is to limit the naval traffic between the Black Sea and the Aegean, and by extension, the high seas. In order do that, the Convention regulates the traffic through three "straits": the Dardanelles, the Sea of Marmara and the Bosporus. With the exception of the latter, the straits would *not* be affected by the construction of the canal. Traffic through the Dardanelles of the Sea of Marmara would still be subject to the convention.

Comment: Maybe their point of view would be that the Montreux Convention only covers water ways existing at that time and not newly created canals? One would probably need a legal expert to comment on that.

Comment: I think this is merely a matter of English grammar. The term 'straits' is singular, not plural; it refers to a narrow, constrained passage of water. It takes a seemingly plural form because it presents multiple navigational issues, not because it includes multiple waterways. A canal bypassing a straits would not automatically be part of the straits.

Comment: @TedWrigley where do you get the idea that "straits" is singular?  Have a look at Wikipedia's [list of straits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_straits).  Note that the very few names where plural "straits" appears refer to geographical features that comprise multiple straits.

Comment: @phoog: (from the dictionary (much as I dislike arguing from dictionaries), which says: *"strait | strāt | - noun - 1. (**also straits**) a narrow passage of water connecting two seas or two other large areas of water"* (emphasis mine). This is common usage: the Strait of Gibraltar and the Straits of Gibraltar are synonyms, with the second being (arguably) more common. The usage is similar to how the term 'rapids' is used with respect to a (singular) rough patch of a river.

Comment: @TedWrigley the plural form may be more common in your experience.  It is certainly not so in mine.  Regardless, the fact that "strait," singular, is in widespread use (even if it is less common), coupled with the fact that it is listed as such in the dictionary (with the form you emphasized as an alternative) means that the statement "'straits' is singular" is incorrect.  In any event, the treaty uses the plural because it covers a passage over three distinct bodies of water.  (Furthermore, the official text of the treaty is in French, where "détroit" is also used in the singular.)

Comment: @phoog: You understand what I mean, and so does Erdoğan (since that's the heart of his claim). You're free to disagree, but my point is still valid, and you are making a lot of noise over something that isn't worth the effort. Chill, dude...

Comment: @TedWrigley actually, I don't understand what you mean.  That is, even leaving aside the quibble about usage, I don't understand why you think that the use of "straits" to refer to a singular "strait" would have any impact on the interpretation of the treaty or on the validity of the question posed here.  Whether we say "bypassing the Bosporus straits doesn't allow bypassing the Sea of Marmara and the Dardanelles straits" or "bypassing the Bosporus strait doesn't allow bypassing the Sea of Marmara and the Dardanelles strait," the question is the same.

Comment: Whoever downvoted the question, would you please explain how it doesn't show any research effort, is unclear or not useful? I'm willing to improve it based on such feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

According to president Erdogan, the new canal [would be](https://www.al-monitor.com/originals/2021/04/who-benefits-if-erdogan-scraps-key-maritime-treaty) outside the scope of the convention (if that's what you're asking)

> In an interview in January 2020, Erdogan was asked whether Canal Istanbul would effectively undo the Montreux Convention. “Don’t worry about Montreux,” he replied. “It is binding for the Bosporus only. Canal Istanbul is outside of its scope.”

---

I can't access either of the articles cited in Wikipedia, but why that might matter... is that the convention [forbids](https://theconversation.com/what-the-montreux-convention-is-and-what-it-means-for-the-ukraine-war-178136) e.g. submarines of non-littoral nations from entering the Black Sea. But if the convention doesn't apply to the canal, then e.g. American, UK, or French subs may use it to enter the Black Sea.

[There](https://www.trtworld.com/magazine/what-does-the-montreux-accord-say-about-closing-black-sea-access-to-russia-55083) also more complicated limits on military surface vessels of non-littoral countries:

> There is also limited naval presence provided for non-Black Sea states. For example, they cannot pursue expedition[ary] operations, nor have a ship pass that is larger than 10,000 tonnes. A non-Black Sea country’s ships cannot exceed a total of 30,000 tonnes at any time, and are allowed to stay in the region for no more than 21 days.

Potentially, these treaty limits [could](https://www.swp-berlin.org/en/publication/canal-istanbul-turkeys-controversial-megaproject) also be bypassed (or not enforced) by Turkey's with respect to non-Black Sea NATO allies if their ships were using the canal, given the Turkish position that the convention would no apply to the canal.

On the other hand, Turkey has apparently [given](https://www.barrons.com/news/russia-says-reassured-by-turkey-about-controversial-canal-01625069707) assurances to Russia that such things won't happen through the new canal.

It's also worth noting that the UK and France are signatories
of the Montreux convention, so they may consider themselves bound by
this treaty's terms limiting their military fleet presence in the Black Sea
regardless of how Turkey interprets these in relation to the [new] canal. The USA however is not a
signatory of Montreux, so [under a good US-Turkey relations assumption] a US government
is mostly constrained (in these regards) only by what Turkey decides to enforce regarding
"non Black Sea Powers" (and their own/US judgement regarding suitability of deploying fleet
assets in the Back Sea, of course). As a footnote, during the Potsdam conference, the US rather [agreed](https://history.state.gov/historicaldocuments/frus1951v05/d635) to limit
the presence of non-Black Sea Powers warships, but not to any concrete terms.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have updated the question to clarify.